# Imagined inductive proof of Sylow's (existence) theorem

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory

I think many people share my sentiment that existing proofs of Sylow's theorems, although very clever and amusing, are not "conceptual" or "explanatory"; it seems to me like a massive coincidence that every finite group has a Sylow $p$-subgroup for every prime $p$.

I have thought about this question only very superficially, so I don't have a lot to offer, but here goes:

Suppose we *didn't* know that every finite group has a Sylow $p$-subgroup for every prime $p$, but we *did* know this for finite *simple* groups.

Now, I want to imagine how an inductive proof of the existence of Sylow subgroups might go.

**Hypothetical Premise:** We know that every finite **simple** group has a Sylow $p$-subgroup for every prime $p$. This is also the base case of our inductive proof.

**Inductive Step:** Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $M\triangleleft G$ be a maximal normal subgroup. Since $|M|<|G|$, we apply the inductive hypothesis to see that $M$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Since $G/M$ is simple, we know that $G/M$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Now, given this, we wish to construct a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. How could we do this?

Comment: Induction on what?

Comment: On the order of the group.

Comment: What if $p\mid |G|$ but $p\nmid |G/H$? Aside from the lifting question …

Comment: In that case, a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/H$ would just be the trivial group, and a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ would be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.